# Simple permutation multiplication of two 4-cycles from $S_4$, specifically, $ (1324)(1423)$.

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

For some reason I am confused on how to multiply these together with $4$ elements. I can do it with $2$ elements but theres a little gap in my logic and I am sure one of you can help me with a simple clarification of where the elements get sent to. Thanks!

Comment: They're inverse permutations!

Comment: @Bernard is right, $(1324)$ is clearly the inverse of $(1423)$, so the product is the identity.

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong here. Sorry, @Bernard.  I need some coffee, errr expresso, as I'm going on 4p.m., after awaking at 1:00 am!!

Comment: See how easy it is to admit errors, @Bernard? And/or apologize for making a mistake? :-)  You should try it sometime!  It ain't a sign of weakness, rather a sign of strength.  Though I know it's tough for some to admit they're human, just like the rest of us.  Cheers!

Comment: Everyone  (and me in particular) makes errors, mostly due to thinking shortcuts. Some are just typos, others *lapsus calami*…

Comment: For everyone's amusement: [math experts provide perfect recipe for expresso](https://www.theguardian.com/food/2020/jan/22/maths-experts-secret-perfect-espresso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma=(1324), \tau=(1423)$.

Then from right to left, we have

$$\begin{align}
1&\stackrel{\tau}{\mapsto}4\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}1,\\
2&\stackrel{\tau}{\mapsto}3\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}2,\\
3&\stackrel{\tau}{\mapsto}1\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}3,\\
4&\stackrel{\tau}{\mapsto}2\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto}4.
\end{align}$$

Thus $(1324)(1423)={\rm id},$ the identity permutation.

Comment: Yes ok this makes sense now because I knew that this product was the identity. I thought you just keep sending to the next element instead of jumping to the next group to see where it was sent to, thats where my logic got messed up. Cool thanks for the clarification

Comment: You're welcome, @PhysicsBish :)

Comment: Nice, @Shaun. +1.  I'm sipping on expresso as we speak!!

Comment: Thank you, @amWhy. Enjoy your espresso!

Comment: @Shaun  Clearly, I *need* it!

Comment: @Shaun, could you help me with a related issue, maybe you commented on this post, but I was trying to find the other sylow $2$-subgroups of $S4$ by conjugation: $\sigma \tao \sigma^{-1}$ Someone helped me by explaining elements I could use and I set this up $(34)(1324)(34)^{-1}$ and this was using an element from $H$ (1324) which was the $1st$ subgroup of $S4$ given in the question. Hope this is enough context...just need to figure out that product.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, @PhysicsBish, but to compute $\rho\pi\rho^{-1}$ for permutations $\rho,\pi,$ with $\pi=(p_{1,1}\dots p_{n_1, 1})\dots(p_{1,m}\dots p_{n_m, m})$, make use of the fact that $$\rho\pi\rho^{-1}=(\rho(p_{1,1})\dots \rho(p_{n_1, 1}))\dots(\rho(p_{1,m})\dots \rho(p_{n_m, m})).$$ Does that answer your question?

Comment: So yes I know about that, but for some reason permutations are the hardest thing in group theory for me haha. So in my case how would I actually write it out using that notation.

Comment: @PhysicsBish: The product would be $$\begin{align}(34)(\color{red}{1324})(34)^{-1}&=((34)(\color{red}{1})(34)(\color{red}{3})(34)(\color{red}{2})(34)(\color{red}{4}))\\ &=(1423).\end{align}$$ I'm not sure if this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes because I got the same answer so it helps support what I was doing. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, @PhysicsBish. Again :)

Comment: Haha yes I know I am needy. Makes me feel like I should stick to physics haha. But I will keep trying!

Comment: Nah, you're good. I doubt anyone here minds, @PhysicsBish.

Comment: Yes I will be on here alot for the remainder of the semester since we went online. So lots of help is welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

I'll add an explanation on how the determine very simply the inverse of a cycle (and thus see instantly that in your case, the cycles are inverses of each other):

If $\gamma=(a_1\,a_2\,\dots\,a_{n-1}\,a_n)$ is any cycle, imagine it consists of $n$ points on a circle, one after the other counterclockwise. The inverse cycle $\gamma^{-1}$ consists of the same points, one after the other, but clockwise, so that we get, always starting with $a_1$:
$$ \gamma^{-1}=(a_1\,a_n\,a_{n-1}\,\dots\,a_2).$$